# Remote Image loads correctly using List, but does not load when using ScrollView with embeded VStack with SwitUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am fetching a remote image inside a `List`. This works correctly.
But It does not work if I place the code inside a ScrollView

```
ScrollView {
   HStack {
```

I have provided the sample XCode 11-Beta SwiftUI [project here](https://github.com/patchthecode/Bugg/archive/master.zip). Just download and run. Once downloaded, look at the `ContentView.swift` file. (see image)

[image]

Comment the part that does not work, and uncomment the part that works to see the difference. List works, but scrollView fails.

Any Idea why?

[**UPDATE**]: 
I have now changed the code on the `struct BuggedView` to the following:

```
struct BuggedView : View {
    @ObjectBinding var viewModel = EventController.ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {

            GeometryReader() { x in
                ScrollView {
                    ForEach(0..<self.viewModel.events.count) { index in
                        EventComponent(event: self.viewModel.events[index]).padding(.top).frame(width: x.size.width)
                    }
                }
            }

            List {
                Spacer().frame(height: 183)
                ForEach(0..<self.viewModel.events.count) { index in
                    EventComponent(event: self.viewModel.events[index]).padding(.top)
                }
            }.offset(x: 200, y: 0)
        }//.frame(width:400, height: 400)
    }
}
```

With this change, you can see both versions of the image on the screen at the same time. In the updated code, notice i have some commented out Frame code. Well here are the result

1. With frame code commented - It Does not work
2. With frame code un-commented - It Does work

SwiftUI bug maybe?

Comment: Both of the examples in the project worked for me. (Note: I did remove all of the comments though as they seemed poorly formatted in the version I opened)

Comment: I do not understand how this is so. It is not working at all for me. Im using XCode11-Beta-1

Comment: But seriously, what's with the downvotes?

Comment: ive gotten more down votes for no reason... Does Stackoverflow have bots? Is there a way to know who downvoted? Why cant they put an upgrade that users must leave a reason for the downvote? This is dumb. I think i'll delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in almost certainly a SwiftUI bug to report to Apple that should be fixed at some point. The .frame modifier should have no effect like you're seeing.

Comment: issue fixed in beta3